# Is it good practice to make an NSSplitView the root view for a view controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

Is it good practice to use an NSSplitView as the root view for a view controller? I am relatively new to Objective-C OSX development and can not seem to find an answer regarding this topic. I noticed that NSViews were created by default as the root view in IB but I normally remove it and assign a new NSSplitView as the root view for a view controller that needs a multi-pane layout. Any OSX veterans out there know if this is ok? I am trying to keep nested views to a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it good practice to use an NSSplitView as the root view for a view controller?

I'd say it's not necessarily good or bad practice to try and make your Window's root view an NSSplitView (especially because the designers of NSWindow declared it's `rootView` property to be completely type-independent (`id`)).  A argument can be made that flatter view hierarchies are always a good thing.  But, then again, the argument also could be made that the designers of NSWindow intended it's `rootView` to be as close to an NSView as possible.  Either way, make sure that your code reflects this change and casts the value of `rootView` where appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just wanted to make sure this wasn't a well-known mistake that beginners like me might make. So far all of my NSSplitview views are working fine as the root view.

Comment: The way I see it, you're just providing a subclass of NSView anyhow.  It's all good.